# Is there a maximum number of views args?

Tags: 7, views

I have an argument list of 300 or so UIDs which I'm passing to a view using hook_views_pre_view, and it dies on me. If I chop that argument list down to ~200 or so, it completes.

Is there a limit to the number of arguments, or is there a setting somewhere that is killing it?

Comment: Can you provide more specific information on what your view settings or code is?  If there is recursion, your problem could be involved with your settings.php limits for nesting (although I would expect an error message to show up if that is the problem).

Comment: Well, all the more complicated stuff involving recursion is already handled by the time I get the list of UIDs, so that isn't the point of failure. My view is simply requesting users with an argument for manager id (a field on the user entity). It's failing with no helpful messages or anything, just dying.

Comment: What does the actual SQL look like?  Is it by any chance getting extremly large by repeating some subqueries?

Comment: If it's dying you could maybe try to enable php error display, so you can see what actually is failing